# display buttons on the same line at opposite sides of the page

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have left and right buttons that I want to display as navigation buttons at the top and bottom of some content on a page like this:

```
<div style="float: right;">     
    <button class="right">Right button</button>
</div>
<div>       
    <button class="left">Left button</button>
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sagittis faucibus
feugiat. Suspendisse felis tortor, sodales quis scelerisque a, malesuada lobortis erat.
Etiam vel lectus vitae nulla imperdiet dapibus. Curabitur accumsan pretium viverra. 
Vivamus sit amet gravida ante. Aenean elit lorem, aliquet porta sollicitudin non, 
elementum aliquam massa. Ut magna arcu, malesuada lacinia rutrum ornare, accumsan sed 
eros.</p>

<div style="float: right;">     
    <button class="right">Right button</button>
</div>
<div>       
    <button class="left">Left button</button>
</div>
```

The problem I have (as seen [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/P2rNC/1/)) is that if I only have my right buttons but not my left buttons, using float floats the button to the right of my paragraph (which is normal because that's what comes after the button), but if I use text-align: right instead of float right, everything works fine. Is there a better way I can do this without having to check for conditions to see if my left buttons exist and change my float to text-align?

Thank you

Comment: Your `right` and `left` should be classes instead of id's. Id's are for unique identification.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use float:right, it's ok with

```
<div style="text-align: right;clear:left;">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put

```
p {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}
```

that should fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/P2rNC/2/

Comment: The top-right button is not on the same line compared to the other top-right buttons

Comment: @user765368 I don't see any differences, can you please explain?

Comment: After using clear both, the <Right button> touches the paragraph. The other buttons do not touch the paragraph

Comment: @user765368 Don't know how to fix that, sorry! Best to go with `text-align` then.